# How do you convert a rust Vec into a reference to an array

Tags: rust, vector

What is the best way to convert a Vec to an array in the latest versions of rust? (Assuming that the type inside the Vec is the same type you need in the array.)

i.e. to resolve errors such as:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/form.rs:96:20
   |
96 |             gloss: &gloss,
   |                    ^^^^^^ expected `&[&Gloss<'_>]`, found `&Vec<Gloss<'_>>`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[&gloss::Gloss<'_>]`
              found reference `&Vec<gloss::Gloss<'_>>`
```

Or:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lexeme.rs:58:24
   |
58 |                 gloss: &entry,
   |                        ^^^^^^ expected `&[&str]`, found `&Vec<&&str>`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[&str]`
              found reference `&Vec<&&str>`
```

(I have a build.rs file that is parsing text input and creating static/const arrays that will never change, so I can't use `Vec` in the struct's)

Comment: Instead of errors, can you post the relevant code which is generating this error?

Comment: None of your errors describe a reference to an array they all are references to **slices**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not turning a `Vec` into an array. You are attempting to turn a `Vec` **of owned values** into a slice of **references**. They contain different types so the conversion can not be made without allocating additional space. You likely need to update your function signature to accept `&[Gloss<'_>]` instead of `&[&Gloss<'_>]`.

Using `&[&str]` is fine, but `Vec<&&str>` seems like it may be a mistake due to the double reference. Perhaps you are collecting from an iterator of `&&str`?

No conversion is needed if you get the types correct. i.e.

```
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    items: &'a [&'a str],
    gloss: &'a [Gloss<'a>], // not &Gloss
}

...
let mut items: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
let mut glosses: Vec<Gloss> = Vec::new();
...
let i = MyStruct{
    items: &items,
    gloss: &glosses,
}
```

Comment: I thought there was some kind of special conversion trick I needed to do. If I understand correctly, I just need to get the reference/owner pointer things sorted and it will automatically convert. Im trying that now. Thanks for the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: @Jay, implicit conversion is done by the `Deref` and `DerefMut` traits. Each type can only have a single `Deref` target so it is fairly easy to check in the docs what a type can turn into. However, keep it mind that it can be applied multiple times. In the case of `Vec<T>`, its [deref target type is `[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Deref-for-Vec%3CT,+A%3E). So that means a `&Vec<T>` can implicitly turn into `&[T]` and `&mut Vec<T>` can implicitly turn into `&mut [T]`. `[T]` does not implement `Deref` so these are the only types it can be implicitly converted to.